# Experience Profile 403 error

Tags: sxa, xconnect, experience-profile

The `Experience Profile` shows the correct data with no console errors when I logged into `Sitecore` for the first time but refreshing the page gives the error `An error has occurred.`

[image: error]

The only way to see the data is to close the browser, open a new browser session, and logged into `Sitecore` but refreshing the page will bring the error again.

I am using `Sitecore 10.1`

Did anyone experience any similar issues?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Different issues can cause 403 errors in Sitecore Experience Profile and Experience Analytics. Please can you check Sitecore log file at the time when you get the 403 error and add any error message details to the question?

Answer (score 2):

Without log entries it will be hard to help, but if I had to guess I would say you might be facing one of the following issues:

1. The application pool for your Sitecore instance does not have read access to the xConnect cert or your cert has expired. You can check both easily enough. To check if access is the issue, add `everyone` with read access to the required cert, then refresh the page. To check if the cert has expired, then simply check the `Expiration Date` column in MMC.

*Note: You will want to find the cert in MMC by thumbprint, and you get the
thumbprint from the AppSettings.config file in your xConnect
instance.*

[image: manage permissions for a cert in MMC]

2. You have multiple Sitecore instances installed on the same machine. I have seen some strange things happen where this is the case, one of them being that the analytics dashboards break. To fix this in dev, I just generate a self-signed cert and update all the configuration with the new thumbprint.
3. Your xConnect instance is configured with a different cert thumbprint than the one that your Sitecore instance is using. Easy enough to check, open the ConnectionString.config file in your Sitecore instance, then open the AppSettings.config file in your xConnect instance, then compare the value in the 'validateCertificateThumbprint' app setting from xConnect against the thumbprint in the ConnectionString file (screenshot below) from your Sitecore instance.

[image: example thumbprint in connection strings file]

Hope this helps!